# Trapping PowerPoint 2010 events while doing presentation

Tags: add-in, powerpoint

Is there a way I can trap event when a presenter switches to a slide on PowerPoint 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out myself.

We can do that using VSTO. Below link has some information to get started

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb960904(office.12).aspx#PPT2007CreatingAddIns_ReactingtoanApplicationLevelEvent

Comment: You can accept your own answer by clicking the hollow checkmark next to the up/down arrows on this answer.